# How to wait after the first task RanToCompletion

Tags: c#, async-await

I was trying to use `Task.WaitAny` to wait a bunch of tasks but what I really want is to wait for the first `RanToCompletion` task instead of `Canceled` tasks.

So when I have a bunch tasks whose status are like:

`0 Canceled;1 Canceled;2 Canceled;3 Canceled;4 Canceled;5 RanToCompletion;`

Ideally I would want `Task.WaitAny` to return `5` but what it returns is `0`.

How should I wait for the first RanToCompletion task?

Comment: What if all the 5 fails? I mean nothing ran to completion. What would you like to do?

Comment: ^
He said the first to rantocompletion, so he probably have more than five and just waits for a single task to complete.

Comment: @RonaldEstacion My question is what if everything failed. 5 is just a number inferred from question .

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel Well because in this context there is no failed, there is only canceled.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Let's assume we can return some other numbers, say -1, if all tasks completed but none of them ran to completion?

Comment: Why not just write a helper method that works the way you want it to? I.e. ignores the non-RanToCompletion tasks when waiting on a collection of Tasks? Just because the exact feature isn't in .NET, that doesn't mean it's all that hard to write for oneself. (Heck, off the top of my head I can think of several convenience-method type features I'd been re-implementing repeatedly over the years, until they were finally added in 4.5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing available out of the box. We need to write some helper method as noted in comments.

Here's an implementation using `TaskCompletionSource`.

```
public class MyTask
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<Task> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Task>();

    private readonly Task[] tasks;
    private int numberOfTasks;
    private MyTask(Task[] tasks)
    {
        if (tasks.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No tasks");
        }

        this.tasks = tasks;
        this.numberOfTasks= tasks.Length;
    }

    private int WaitAnyInternal()
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            task.ContinueWith(task1 => completionSource.TrySetResult(task1), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        }
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            task.ContinueWith(task1 =>
            {
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref numberOfTasks) == 0)
                {
                    completionSource.SetCanceled();
                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
        }

        try
        {
            completionSource.Task.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.OfType<OperationCanceledException>().Any())
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return Array.IndexOf(tasks, completionSource.Task.Result);
    }

    public static int WaitAnyRanToCompletion(params Task[] tasks)
    {
        return new MyTask(tasks).WaitAnyInternal();
    }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    throw new Exception();
});//Faulted task

var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
});//Will complete first

var task3 = Task.Delay(10000);//Will complete, but not first

int index = MyTask.WaitAnyRanToCompletion(task1, task2, task3);
//Index will be 1, which means task2
```